# MySQL Script 1064 Error

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Ive got a wordpress site running on a VPS server and now need to migrate this to another VPS. So I've run an Export script from EMS MySql Manager(mymanager) that exported all the tables and data as a script.

Ive then gone over to my new server, with the same version of MySQL and MySql Manager installed, and tried to run the script.

However, the script keeps failing on the following block:

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_commentmeta` (
`meta_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`comment_id` BIGINT(20) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`meta_key` VARCHAR(255) COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`meta_value` LONGTEXT COLLATE utf8_general_ci,
PRIMARY KEY USING BTREE (`meta_id`) COMMENT '',
INDEX `comment_id` USING BTREE (`comment_id`) COMMENT '',
INDEX `meta_key` USING BTREE (`meta_key`) COMMENT ''
)   
 ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 AVG_ROW_LENGTH=16384 CHARACTER SET utf8= COLLATE utf8_general_ci COMMENT=''
;
```

With (typically) this error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'COMMENT '',     INDEX `comment_id` USING BTREE
>   (`comment_id`) COMMENT '',     IN' at line 6

Any ideas as to how to resolve this and why the original DB is working fine and this script exports, yet it causes issue when trying to run the resultant script.???

Comment: If the `COMMENT`s are going to be empty you can just remove them

Comment: Ok, so i did a find and replace and that got rid of most. But, it turns out there were some at the end of every script block that didnt have a space before the "COMMENT" bit. So my guess is its some bug somewhere along the lines that caused that. I manually removed these and it seemed to fully run the script. Just need to test it all thoroughly now though to make sure those COMMENTS were needed for something weird. ;-)

Comment: If @ExplosionPills you want to make that an answer, Ill happily mark you as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can tell you can't put `COMMENT`s on keys, but this may vary based on the MySQL version.  Anyway if the comments are just going to be empty anyway, you don't even need them.  Just remove

```
COMMENT ''
```

from your ddl.